# What grammatical position hold slogans and mottos? Is this the same across languages?

Tags: cross-linguistic, tense-aspect-mood

"Make America Great Again." "Proletariat of the world, unite." "Move the way you want." "Rewards reimagined." "Death to fascism, freedom to the people." "Éirinn go Brách." "Ein Volk, ein Reich, ein Führer." "Every man a king." "Hasta la victoria siempre." "Liberté, Égalité, Fraternité."

Some slogans, like the first two examples, seem to be imperatives, but the similarity to normal language falls after the resemblance to. What's up with phrases like "death to fascists"? Is a verb implied? I don't know German grammar for example, but why are the nouns of the above Nazi slogan nominative? Why do lists of nouns, like the Nazi slogan again as well as liberty/equality/fraternity, seem to say something, even though they're just laundry lists? The Uber tagline (example three), what mode is "move"?

These questions can multiply, but the singular question that heads them is: **do slogans occupy a special place in the grammars of various languages**? What is this tenseless, dictionary-form way of speaking, and why does it seem to follow the same convention across (...European) languages, whether it does or not?

Comment: I meant to include more advertising examples but I found a nice list of political slogans that demonstrates this jilted manner of talk.
Question for another day, for another forum: why are complete-sentence slogans like "Slavery is a social, moral, and political wrong" so rare?
Motivator for the question is pretty much that that style of speaking bothers me. It's the style of speaking when you're busy and a closer acquaintance than a passing stranger is talking to you. "Where's the remote?" "Couch."

Comment: Some linguists call them verbless directives, e.g. Aikhenvald 2016 https://www.oxfordhandbooks.com/view/10.1093/oxfordhb/9780199591435.001.0001/oxfordhb-9780199591435-e-8#oxfordhb-9780199591435-e-8-div2-12